# es6 arrow functions debugger statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I have a function like that:

```
param => params + 1
```

and I need to put a `debugger` statement inside the function's body. Is adding parenthesis like this:

```
param => { debugger; return params + 1 }
```

the only option?

Comment: Technical note: These are braces, not parentheses.  Not too important here, but when talking things like regex, you need to be explicit.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, thanks, a small example maybe to show a difference?

Comment: `{}` -> braces, `()` -> parentheses, `[]` -> (square) brackets

Comment: @JamesThorpe, ah, I see, thanks a lot for the bothering to mention that

Comment: No probs, just like to help educate on all aspects of a question where possible :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Basic_Syntax) article on arrow functions:

> ```
> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
> ```

You can see that the brace-less syntax requires the code on the right of the arrow to be an *expression*, which is an (unfortunate) [distinction](http://www.2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html) made by the language itself.

Since `debugger` is a statement, using it anywhere an *expression* is expected is a syntax error. One thing you could to to work around this is to transform your debugger statement in an expression which you trick JavaScript into evaluating but not returning, e.g.:

```
function debug(args) {
     debugger;
     return true;
}

params => debug() && params + 1

// or

params => console.log(params) || params + 1
```

The way this works is that because of the way [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) function in JavaScript, this is true:

```
truthyA && B  === B

falsyA || B === B
```

When chaining logical operators, JavaScript evaluates sub-expressions left to right and then act depending on their boolean equivalent. That's why you'll sometimes see `&&` used in place of `if` statements:

```
 if (smth) doStuff();
 // is equivalent to:
 smth && doStuff();
```

Comment: seems like you want to have more upvotes with constant reediting)

Comment: Yes MOAR UPVOTES PLS. No but seriously, SO is very well indexed by Google so other people could end-up on this question in the future, might as well give them the best answer possible. Plus I just like explaining this kind of stuff.

Comment: The comma operator can also be useful in these situations, though it seems most people don't know about it.

Comment: @Yay295 Good point although you'd still have to wrap your lambda body in parentheses because the comma has the [lowest precedence of all operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). So you may as well use braces and colons instead :)

Answer (score 2):

Use console.log with a logical OR operator. This writes the arguments to the console.

```
const add = (x, y) => console.log(x, y) || x + y;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it, which doesn't require defining a function:

```
(() => { debugger; })()
```

It is a self invoking arrow function that calls the `debugger` statement, and it is also an expression.

So in your code you could use:

```
param => (() => { debugger; })() && params + 1
```

It's a bit harder to type, but does the trick anywhere an expression is expected.

Note that if you want `params + 1` to also be executed (e.g. continue after debug statement) you have to return true from the function:

```
(() => { debugger; return true })()
```

Comment: This pauses execution at the breakpoint, but you can't actually debug the values. The arguments are undefined when you hover over them in the dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

have not found decent fat arrow function inline debugger injection yet.
Option:

```
 ()=>console.log(9)?? (()=>{debugger} )() ?? console.log(0)
```

console is a stub of any code. `(()=>{debugger} )()` seems only way to make debugger inline. In your case:

```
param => (()=>{debugger} )() ?? params + 1
```