# Debugging functional react components with implicit return

Tags: reactjs

Seems like this is a really popular syntax in React, making use of the ES6 implicit return and whatnot:

```
const TableRow = ({ product, deleteProduct }) => (
    <tr>
    {   
        Object.keys(product).map( (key) => (                                                          
                    <td key={tdKeys++}>{product[key]}</td>                                            
                    ))                                                                                
    }                                                                                                 
    <td>
        <button className="productsTable__deleteButton"                                               
            onClick={() => deleteProduct(product.id)}>                                                
            Delete                                                                                    
        </button>                                                                                     
    </td>                                                                                             
</tr>
)
```

What's got me kind of cheesed up though, is that it seems impossible to debug. Is there a way to debug the props of this component, without modifying this implicit return?

I could move the content of these parentheses into a return statement, insert some curly braces, and then put a debugger or console log statement in, but this makes me sad. Are there alternatives? (If the app is crashing here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like there are too many options aside from adding a function block. I found an answer here that's interesting: [es6 arrow functions debugger statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513155/es6-arrow-functions-debugger-statement)

> Since debugger is a statement, using it anywhere an expression is
>   expected is a syntax error. One thing you could to to work around this
>   is to transform your debugger statement in an expression which you
>   trick JavaScript into evaluating but not returning, e.g.:

```
function debug(args) {
     debugger;
     return true;
}

params => debug() && params + 1

// or

params => console.log(params) || params + 1
```

**So essentially:** `params => console.log(params) || params + 1` can be a quick workaround.